# window not displaying when compiled and opened

Tags: c

So i am new to c,

my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
    printf("it works!");
    getch(); //getch() before return
    return 0;
}
```

IDE: Dev c++

I compiled it, it is saves as an exe file,
when i double click on the exe file a command prompt window appears for a millisecond and exits,
how can i make the window stay until i close it?

i have read that the `getch()` command makes the window stay but it did not.

Comment: What does the `return` command do?

Comment: `return 0;` is the end of your program. Nothing after that will be executed, so your `getch()` is ignored. Simply move `getch();` before `return 0;`. Or remove `return 0;` line altogether, compiler will handle that on it's own (note: only in `main()` function).

Comment: Please don't spam tags.  Pick a language.

Comment: it did not work tht way too

Comment: @Praveen _it did not work that way too_:, be more explicit.

Comment: @Praveen Yes it did

Comment: ok it worked, sorry i replaced getch() with return 0

Comment: @PaulSanders i am sorry stack overflow suggested it to me the c++ tag

Comment: @Praveen No worries, thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will, if you let it be executed!

`return 0;` returns from the function (in this case, ending the program), so you need it *after* the `getch()`, not before.